# Removing Cloud Zoom and maybe adding fancybox to magento theme

Tags: jquery, magento, fancybox, themes, zooming

I'm trying to get rid of this cloud zoom in my magento theme.  I find it to be annoying on an eCommerce site.  I'd like to swap it out with a fancy box.

http://www.acuity-sports.com/volleyball/2-6mm-collegiate-college-volleyball-net-32-x-3.html

This is my code to pop out a box for the theme.

```
<div class="popup-btn hidden-phone">
        <a id="yt_popup" rel="yt-colorbox" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, $media_image_type)->keepAspectRatio($keepFrame)->backgroundColor($ws_bgcolor)->resize($media_default_image_width); ?>" >zoom</a>        
    </div>
```

Comment: find cloudzoom module in [magento]\app\etc\modules\ then set it to false

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/jquery-lightboxes-fancybox-pirobox-etc.html